# nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting can you help me?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nodemon

my code is; `

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res)=>{
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
        
        !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong password or username !");
   
        const bytes =  CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user.password, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
        const originalPassword= bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        originalPassword !== req.body.password && res.status(401).json('Wrong Password or Username! --this code ');
         const {password, ...info} = user._doc;
         res.status(200).json(info)

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }`
```

I have shared the error and postman request as a screenshot. There is no problem when status returns 200 but when 200 is not I get this error.

How can ı solve?

Comment: Which error? You didn't attach the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly; Errors in Node.js are handled through exceptions. An exception is created using the `throw` keyword.

See here for more information. [Error handling in Node.js](https://nodejs.dev/learn/error-handling-in-nodejs)

Your mistake is here:

```
res.status(401).json({error: "Wrong Password or Username! --this code" });
```

The `res.json()` function sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using the `JSON.stringify()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (req.body.password !== originalPassword) {
  res.status(401).json("Wrong password or username !");
  return;
}
```

I solved like this!

Thank you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and resolved the issue.